# How to create a restful service for signin using spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can I create a /signin restful web service for login form of UI in a spring security based application. How are sessions managed using the spring security?

I have worked by implementing UserDetailsService and then overriding loadUserByUserName. 
I am worried as to how I can create a restful web service which can authenticate user details at time of login.

Comment: What are you authenticating your user against ? DB/LDAP/.. ?

Comment: Database ashish

Answer (score 0):

You have your own implementation of UserDetailsService where you pass the username to the RESTful service which should in turn return a [User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) object with the username, password and authorities loaded.